# Register to open files with custom extension, API 31

Tags: android

My app stores data in `files` in a custom XML-like format using a specified file extension. I want to be able to open files with this extension in my app, such as by selecting the app in the "open with" sheet in other apps (Files, Dropbox, ...)

I have read other SO questions on this subject and have, using those answers, added the following to my manifest:

```
    <application ... >
        <activity android:name=".ImportActivity">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="file"/>
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.odn" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I also tried `android:pathPattern="*.odn"`. Some of the keys I added are probably superfluous as they were added from multiple answers. In any case, I find that my app does not appear as a potential receiver of the file on the "open with" sheet.

I can't be sure but I suspect there is more than one way to do this depending on the target API version, but I can't find a working example.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "Register to open files with custom extension" -- that has never worked well on Android. For the past several years, it has been nearly impossible. In particular, the `file` scheme is largely unused. You can add `content` as a scheme, but a `content` `Uri` only occasionally actually has a file extension. You are still welcome to offer the manifest entry, but just be aware that few users will be able to take advantage of it.

Comment: @CommonsWare ahh I had read this but hoped there might be a way through a newer API feature. Ok, I'll instead implement a file browser and implement importing of files within the app itself. Thanks :)

Comment: "I'll instead implement a file browser" -- see `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for the pointer, I'm going to work on it now :)

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to @CommonsWare for the pointers :) the only thing I would like to improve is that the file picker can't be filtered by file extension, though I believe this is not currently possible in android. I may also make the `Uri` passed into the completion handler nullable and call `fileImportCompletionHandler?.invoke(null)` in the error states. I really love kotlin :)

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private var fileImportCompletionHandler: (Uri.()->Unit)? = null
        
        private val fileImportIntentLauncher = 
            registerForActivityResult(
                ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
            ) { result: ActivityResult ->

                if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                    val intent = result.data
                    intent?.data?.let { uri ->


                        fileImportCompletionHandler?.invoke(uri) ?: run {
                            // TODO() warn
                        }

                        fileImportCompletionHandler = null

  
                    } ?: run {
                        // TODO() warn
                    }

                }
                else {
                    // TODO() warn
                }

        }

        private val importIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {

            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            type = "*/*"

        }

        fun showActionOpenDocument(completion: Uri.()->Unit) {

            fileImportCompletionHandler = completion
            fileImportIntentLauncher.launch(importIntent)

        }
```